# What is the Gaidukov Phenomenon in algae?

Tags: botany

Apparently the Gaidukov Phenomenon occurs in algae so as to enable the algae to absorb the maximum light for photosynthesis. How does this happen?

Comment: This may be helpful. http://www.pnas.org/content/20/5/251.full.pdf

Comment: @Mesentery Thanks a lot!! Obviously this was of great help!! 

Comment: You should provide a better background, and briefly explain the Gaidukov Phenomenon.